# MVC webgrid export to excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel

I want to export the mvc webgrid to excel.The following code is written on view and webgrid ID has been accessed here.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/unconditional /jquery-table2excel/master/src/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    $('#btnExport').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ResultsToTable();
    });

    function ResultsToTable() {
        $("#gvSIExecution").table2excel({
            exclude: ".noExl",
            name: "Results"
        });
    }
});
```

The problem is ,if the webgrid is simple one without any input controls in it
works fine. But if there are any input controls such **textbox**,**checkbox** in it ,then the webgrid gets exported along with textbox with the value in it.

All I need is to display only value in the column not the textbox or checkbox.

[Exported excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSBN0.jpg)
Screenshot of exported excel sheet.

Help me out!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you will need to remove all inputs and send that to grid to excel.

```
$grid = $("#gvSIExecution").clone();
$grid.find("input").remove()
$grid.table2excel({
            exclude: ".noExl",
            name: "Results"
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But am facing a small issue here.
The above code removes the input controls from the webgrid when I click export button.What I require is the input control must be displayed as it is,but it should not be displayed in an exported excel file ,only value should be displayed in the excel sheet.

Comment: @VinayDiddi forgot to clone the element. You can look at the updated code.

Comment: Hi
please help me out in this problem

Am exporting div content of webgrid to excel in jquery using

' $("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
        window.open('data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,' + encodeURIComponent($('div[id$=Tab-DailyAccReg]').html()));
        e.preventDefault();
    });'

it is exporting file but without an extension. The extension I need is **.xlsx**

Comment: $("#btnExport").click(function (e) { window.open('data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,' + encodeURIComponent($('div[id$=Tab-DailyAccReg]').html()));